# C# Lambda ( => )

Tags: c#, lambda

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Good tutorials for lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537303/good-tutorials-for-lambda)
>   [Lambda Explanation and what it is as well as a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333560/lamda-explanation-and-what-it-is-as-well-as-a-good-example)
>   [C# Lambda expression, why should I use this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167343/c-lambda-expression-why-should-i-use-this)

Can someone explain to me how to use this and give me examples? How do we read it?

Example `!=` is read as "not equals to." So `=>` means what?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333560/lamda-explanation-and-what-it-is-as-well-as-a-good-example.

Comment: `!=` and `=>` have nothing in common, except for the `=` character. But that's it.

Comment: Wait... were you actually asking how it should be pronounced when reading it out loud?

Comment: @Frustrated [Pronunciation guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274022/how-do-i-pronounce-as-used-in-lambda-expressions-in-net).

Answer (score 6):

> All lambda expressions use the lambda
>   operator =>, which is read as "goes
>   to". The left side of the lambda
>   operator specifies the input
>   parameters (if any) and the right side
>   holds the expression or statement
>   block. The lambda expression x => x *
>   x is read "x goes to x times x." This
>   expression can be assigned to a
>   delegate type as follows:

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

> the => operator has the same precedence as assignment (=) and is right-associative.

Answer (score 5):

"=>" is lambda operator and is read as "goes to"

Answer (score 5):

This is the lambda operator. Which means 'goes to'. It is used to create lambda expressions which is syntax offered by C# for anonymous methods.

eg. lamda expression `x=>x > 2`. This mean that given x, x goes to x greater than 2. In other words this lambda expression will select x greater than 2.

Anonymous method for the same can be written as

```
delegate(int x){return x > 2;}
```

Comment: Surely its only right to say it will select x greater than 2 if the lambda is used as part of a select. Woudln't it be more accurate to say that it would return true if x > 2 and false otherwise or something similar?

Comment: you are right. I jumbled up both of them. Good Catch

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

The => operator has the same precedence as assignment (=) and is right-associative.

Comment: That's the perfect answer.  And to make it more perfect, I would add "'=>' reads 'goes to'".  :)