# What's the meaning of "=>" in C#?

Tags: c#, syntax, lambda

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# Lambda ( => )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970219/c-lambda)

For instance

```
Messenger.Default.Register<AboutToCloseMessage>(this, (msg) =>
        {
            if (msg.TheContainer == this.MyContainer) // only care if my container.
            {
                // decide whether or not we should cancel the Close
                if (!(this.MyContainer.CanIClose))
                {
                    msg.Execute(true); // indicate Cancel status via msg callback.
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: @Shakti Singh: Can you show us how to search for the `=>` symbol?

Comment: @Shakti Singh: If Rdeluca knew `=>` means "lambda expression" he wouldn't be asking in the first place.

Comment: Yeah.. Had no idea it was called lambda or I would've searched it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a lambda, it allows you to create a function easily.

in your example you can also write:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<AboutToCloseMessage>(this, delegate(Message msg)
{
    if (msg.TheContainer == this.MyContainer) // only care if my container.
    {
        // decide whether or not we should cancel the Close
        if (!(this.MyContainer.CanIClose))
        {
            msg.Execute(true); // indicate Cancel status via msg callback.
        }
    }
});
```

or even

```
Messenger.Default.Register<AboutToCloseMessage>(this, foobar);

// somewhere after //
private void foobar(Message msg)
{
    if (msg.TheContainer == this.MyContainer) // only care if my container.
    {
        // decide whether or not we should cancel the Close
        if (!(this.MyContainer.CanIClose))
        {
            msg.Execute(true); // indicate Cancel status via msg callback.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The

```
=>
```

Operator is used for Lambda Expressions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

It allows you to define an anonymous function "on the fly" and can be used to create delegates or expression tree types.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lambda expression (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

its a lamda expression (Function Argument ) => { Function Body}

The type of the argument can be specified but the complier will generally just interpret it.

Answer (score 0):

That is how you define lambda in C#.  `msg` is the argument, passed to the lambda method, and the rest is the body of the method.

The equivalent of  that is this:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<AboutToCloseMessage>(this, SomeMethod);

void SomeMethod(SomeType msg)
{
    if (msg.TheContainer == this.MyContainer) // only care if my container.
    {
        // decide whether or not we should cancel the Close
        if (!(this.MyContainer.CanIClose))
        {
             msg.Execute(true); // indicate Cancel status via msg callback.
        }
    }
}
```