# What is the "=>" sign in LINQ queries?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

It's amazing how little information there is on this. I found tons of tutorials explaining LINQ, but they don't explain this particular operator:

```
var Results = UserFavoritesContext.UserFavorites.Select(color => color.FavoriteColor);
```

"**x => x.y**"

Can someone please explain how this works? I get the general syntax and am able to use it to make queries, but it's like doing something without knowing what you're doing.

Comment: This is lambda expression syntax, check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970219/c-sharp-lambda

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Suppose you have a list of `people`, and you want to iterate over them. You would write something like:

```
foreach(var person in people)
{
       //do something to person
}
```

Note how you yourself chose the name `person`. It could've been any word, but you basically said "process every single item of the list as my `person` variable".

Now look at this LINQ query:

```
filteredPeopleList = people.Where(person => person.Name == "John");
```

Again, you basically chose `person` as a placeholder name for every object in the original list (one at a time). The above Linq query is equivalent to

```
foreach(var person in people)
{
       if(person.Name == "John")
       {
           filteredPeopleList.Add(person);
       }
}
```

To me, `x => x.y` is basically saying "for every variable we process (let's call it `x`), please perform the following operation on it (`x.y`, get the `y` property)"

I hope that explains it.

**Edit**
As a commenter who now deleted his comment mentioned, this isn't exclusively used in LINQ. A lambda expression doesn't have to iterate over an `IEnumerable`, it can be used to process a single item.
However, LINQ is by far the most common place to encounter lambdas, and I find their use very similar to the `foreach` loop, which is why I picked this example.

Answer (score 2):

The => operator is used in lambda expressions.

The best way to think of this is a type of syntax for writing a function, where the left side of the operator is the parameters for the function and the right side is the body of the function e.g. this is a valid use of a lambda expression where its being used like a function:

```
Func<int, int> incrementFunction = i => i + 1;
int incrementedNumber = incrementFunction(1);
```

The name i in this case is an arbitrary variable name e.g. just like you would name a functions input parameter. Notice I didnt need to declare the input parameters type because the compiler will infer it. Also notice I dont need to include the "return" keyword or enclose the function body in a code block. It doesn't necessarily need any parameters either e.g.

```
Action myAction = () => Console.Write("something");
myAction();
```

When you use it in a linq expression, think of it as though the lambda function is being called on every element in the collection (which I believe is exactly what happens with linq to objects).

Answer (score 1):

It's the syntax of a Lambda expression. If it helps you to remember... in a nutshell, the argument to pass (the parameter) is on the left of the => and the method(s) that use it are on the right hand side of it.

I hope this short summary explains it enough :)

Answer (score 1):

That is a lambda expression, and it can be used as a selector from an object

You can conditionally select (or another operation orderby, count, etc) when the expression is true. For example:

Say you had a list of people and their details: ID, Name, City and Profession.

You could select a single person by using lambda to search for their specific ID:

```
public Person GetByID(int id)
{
Person selectedPerson = people.SingleOrDefault(person => person.ID == id);
return selectedPerson;
}
```

Same could be applied for a select on a city, this would be:

```
public List<Person> GetByCity(string city)
{
List<Person> selectedPeople = people.where(person => person.City == city);
return selectedPeople;
}
```

The lamda expression is where you place your operation variable, so in these cases the condition upon which you select the data. You can use it as a orderby variable much in the same way, in the next example I use two lamdas to perform two seperate functions

```
public List<Person> GetByCity(string city)
{
List<Person> selectedPeople = people.where(person => person.city == city)
.OrderByDescending(person => person.Name);
return selectedpeople;
}
```

I hope this helps at all

Answer (score 1):

**`x => x.y`** is Lambda Expression introduced with C# 3.0. The general syntax is

> parameter => executioncode

The Lambda Expression has 3 parts:

1. x on left hand side is the parameter.This can be a variable,delegate or an anonymous function.
2. => read as "goes to", which acts as separator
3. x.y is an Expression  to be evaluated.

For example, the lambda expression x => x * x specifies a parameter that’s named x and returns the value of x squared (source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)).

Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

They're called Lamda expression:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

```
var Results = UserFavoritesContext.UserFavorites.Select(color => color.FavoriteColor);
```

is similar to:

```
List<UserFavorite> Results = new List<UserFavorite>();
foreach(var item in UserFavorites)
{
   Results.Add(item.FavoriteColor);
}
```

Comment: more like a `yield return ...` than a list : lazy evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to Linq.

It is the way you write a lambda expression.
The arrow **=>** is the delimiter between your lambda parameters and its body.