# How ToDictionary in c# works?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections, lambda

I am wondering how this statement works while converting a list to a dictionary.
The expression is much like

```
OtherList = MyList.ToDictionary(x => x.MyId, y => y.MyName);
```

can anybody explain that why there are two variables x and y ? And how they work together ? Cant I use the same variable twice ?

Comment: They are two separate [lambda expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb397687.aspx).

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970219/c-sharp-lambda) is another duplicate. Note that both variables could have the same name(f.e. `x`) since they are in different scopes.

Comment: If you're used to other LINQ, like `Select`, you see pretty much this same code.  The difference with `ToDictionary` is that, to obtain the information it needs, it simply requires two methods rather than one.

Comment: The first lambda is selecting the key to use in the dictionary from each item in your list.  The second selects the value.  The variable names `x` and `y` are arbitrary and both represent one item in the list.