# What does '=>' do in C#?

Tags: c#, operators

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Lamda Explanation and what it is as well as a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333560/lamda-explanation-and-what-it-is-as-well-as-a-good-example)
>   [What is the => token called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879860/what-is-the-token-called)

I have seen this code:

```
myContext.SomeEntities.Single(x => x.code == code);
```

And I don´t know what does the => operator do.

Every search on google about the operator returns no results.

Thank you.

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873603/whats-the-point-of-a-lambda-expression

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274022/how-do-i-pronounce-as-used-in-lambda-expressions-in-net

Comment: @Steve: Is that even a duplicate? That user in your question knows what a lambda expression is, @Javiere does not. He is asking what => does much like someone would ask what the ! sign does.

Comment: google can't handle searching for `=>` search for lambda instead.

Comment: @0A0D - I dunno, that q seemed to cover the required ground to me.  Syntax and semantics.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `=>` operator designates a [Lambda Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx):

> A *lambda expression* is an anonymous function that can contain expressions and statements, and can be used to create delegates or expression tree types.
>
> All lambda expressions use the lambda operator =>, which is read as "goes to". The left side of the lambda operator specifies the input parameters (if any) and the right side holds the expression or statement block. The lambda expression x => x * x is read "x goes to x times x." This expression can be assigned to a delegate type as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Func<int, int> func = x => x * x;
    int j = func(5);
    // j == 25
}
```

Comment: I've also seen/heard "maps to" instead of "goes to".

Comment: +1 for taking more time, then the other answers, to copy and paste a quote (even though this has already been covered) and providing an example.

Comment: @Richard: Or "for which"

Answer (score 2):

Lambda expressions, very cool.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It signals that the code is a lambda expression.

More info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is defining a lambda. You can read it "x goes to x.code equals code," and it means that given x, return the result of the given comparison.

Answer (score 1):

They are related to lambda expressions.

You can read about Lambda Expressions here:
http://www.rvenables.com/2009/03/practical-introduction-to-lambda-expressions/